# Drupal 6 - make a module for every block of dynamic information?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a Drupal 6 website with about 20 pages. Inside every page, I need to create a lot of widgets with information either stored inside the database or from external web services. Most of the time, a "view" (from [the view module](http://drupal.org/project/views)) is just not enough to solve the requirement.

Up until now, any time I need such a widget, I create a new module which implements  hook_block. Then, I drag and drop this new module inside the panel I want. I will need to create about 20 modules. This works pretty good. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct-drupal-strategy and I would love to receive some feedback from experienced Drupal developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module can expose as many blocks as you want (in theory, admin/build/blocks will teach you otherwise ;)).

Have a look at the documentation of [hook_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6), you just need to extend yours to return multiple block infos and then decided which one to show based on the $delta.

So you don't need 20 separate modules, maybe 2-3 and group the blocks somehow together because just a single module might be hard to maintain. The thing is that every single module makes your site a tiny bit slower (at least one more file to load, module_implements() needs to loop over every module for every hook and so on).

Without more information , it's hard to give any better advice. Maybe you could expose your data to views, or write a views plugin to display it in the way you want it, or...

Comment: Thank you! Right now I have a module called "myapp" and inside it a function called "myapp_block". How do I create and call other blocks inside the same module? Do they live in different functions or do I need some switch statement? How would I pass a parameter to my module?

Comment: +1 for both suggestions, especially exposing to a view, since it seems to be almost good enough, but not quite.  Custom views code can be quite powerful.  I've had ajaxified "add to cart" buttons as a views field.  Well worth the initial investment to learn.

Comment: See the documentation of hook_block(): http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6 (and barraponto's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Although Berdir's answer is pretty good, I'm impressed there's no link to any documentation in it. [hook_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) is meant for several blocks, and they can share functions that build their content. The API page is good, the example it gives defines two blocks at once.

You should notice each defined block has a delta (a key in the $blocks array). You can have dynamic deltas and use values in it to fetch data (passing a nid or uid and getting related content, for example).

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add that, updated my answer and upvoted yours.